# Android Coil custom extension function not working

Tags: android, coil

Objective: load the image only if present in the coil cache.
Using the extension function `imageView.load(url) {}`
--you cannot configure the request-- (update: wrong assumption), so you must write this whole code instead ([docs](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/getting_started/)):

```
            val imageLoader = holder.myImageView.context.imageLoader
            val request = ImageRequest.Builder(holder.myImageView.context)
                .data(url)
                .target(holder.myImageView)
                .networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
                .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .build()
            imageLoader.enqueue(request)
```

This code works so I'm trying to move this to an own extension function **ImageView.loadFromCache()** like this:

```
fun ImageView.loadFromCache(
    data: Any?
): Disposable {

    val noCacheBuilder : ImageRequest.Builder.() -> Unit = {
        ImageRequest.Builder(context.applicationContext)
            .networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
            .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
    }
    return load(data, builder = noCacheBuilder)
}
```

Now I can call `holder.myImageView.loadFromCache(url)` which executes without error but here my policies are completely ignored, any idea why?

Comment: Where is the `load()` function coming from that you are calling in your `return` statement? `noCacheBuilder` seems like it is not actually doing anything -- it creates an object that seems like it is ignored, as your lambda expression is typed to evaluate to `Unit`.

Comment: load() is a coil extension function, check the linked "docs"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```kotlin
    val noCacheBuilder : ImageRequest.Builder.() -> Unit = {
        ImageRequest.Builder(context.applicationContext)
            .networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
            .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
    }
```

with:

```kotlin
    val noCacheBuilder : ImageRequest.Builder.() -> Unit = {
        this.networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
            .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
    }
```

The receiver of that lambda expression is an `ImageRequest.Builder`. Your current code is ignoring it and is creating a new one, which then never leaves that lambda expression (as it returns `Unit`).

Comment: Wow, I was not realizing that, that worked. I just also saw that part of my assumption was wrong, you acutally can also call             holder.myImageView.load(url) {
                networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
                diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            }